# Why are parts of my mesh see through?

Tags: 3d-view

I have a simple mesh that, no matter what I do, displays certain faces as transparent:
[image: The model displays certain faces as if backface culling is on (it's not)]

This is just modeled from an image plane. Backface culling is off, normals have been recalculated and flipped, x-ray is off, but I can't get rid of the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Materials section, under "Settings", check and see in in "Blend Mode" if Alpha Blend is on. You can either choose to disable Alpha Blend or you can Disable "Show Backface". See picture. [image]

Comment: Thank you! That was it!